# What is Struct in Swift's the equivalent expression for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a task need to rewrite swift code with Objective-c, my question is what is the equivalent expression/code to rewrite struct using Objective-C

```
Struct A {
    weak var b: B?
}
```

Comment: What is the context?  That kind of struct is usually a wrapper to have weak references stored in a container.  In Objective-C, you'd just make it a class, instead.  Or you could use one of the CoreFoundation containers which allow weak references.

Comment: yes, as you said, it is a wrapper. thanks, I will use a class instead.